# Keep tab menu li child active when returned back to that parent menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, tabs

I'm building a real estate site on Wordpress and have been doing some light HTML, CSS & JS on my own. I'm a complete novice when it comes to this stuff, but have been getting by..... until now.

I built this Tab / Sub-Tab Menu to display any active listings at any particular property. The structure starts with two parent tab menus "FOR SALE" & "FOR RENT". Each of those parent menus have sub-tab menus "ALL", "1BR", "2BR" & "3BR+".

I built the parent tabs with visual composer in Wordpress, but it will not allow me to nest tab elements within tab elements, so for the second or sub-tab menu I had to build it from scratch from a tutorial I found online using very basic javascript. Upon initial arrival of the page, the "FOR SALE" > "ALL" menus are active and showing listings well.

THE PROBLEM: is that when you navigate to view listings "FOR RENT" none of the sub-menus are active or displaying listings. The user has to actually click on one of the four sub-menu options to see availability. Same happens when you go back to "FOR SALE".

I want, by default, the sub-menu tab "ALL" to be active and showing listings when you click "FOR SALE" or "FOR RENT". What would be a plus on this is if it remembered which sub-menu the user was on if they were switching back and forth between the two parent items.

Please help!

LINK: http://www.eastvalleyurban.com/blank-community-template-2

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".tab_content").hide();
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); 

    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".tab_content").hide();
        var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
        $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn(); 
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="tabs"> 
        <li class="active" rel="tab5">ALL</li>
        <li rel="tab6">1BR</li>
        <li rel="tab7">2BR</li>
        <li rel="tab8">3BR</li>
    </ul>

<div class="tab_container"> 

     <div id="tab5" class="tab_content"> 

        <script charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript" id="idxwidgetsrc-45380" src="http://www.eastvalleyurban.idxbroker.com/idx/customshowcasejs.php?widgetid=45380"></script>

     </div><!-- #tab5 -->
     <div id="tab6" class="tab_content"> 

       [FOR RENT - 1BR CONTENT] 

     </div><!-- #tab6 -->
     <div id="tab7" class="tab_content">

       [FOR RENT - 2BR CONTENT] 

     </div><!-- #tab7 -->
     <div id="tab8" class="tab_content"> 

       <script charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript" id="idxwidgetsrc-45381" src="http://www.eastvalleyurban.idxbroker.com/idx/customshowcasejs.php?widgetid=45381"></script>

     </div><!-- #tab8 --> 

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your 'RENT' or 'SALE' tab in html???
Assuming you have a block for RENT and another for SALE with a common class as 'rentsale'. Then in javascript you can write it as :

```
$('.rentsale').on('click',function(e){
 $(this).find('ul.tabs li:first-child').trigger('click');
})
```

Write this inside document.ready at third line after `$(".tab_content:first").show();`

If you have ids like 'rent' and 'sale' in html for rent and sale block then write

```
$('#rent,#sale').on('click',function(e){
 $(this).find('ul.tabs li:first-child').trigger('click');
})
```

I hope this solves your problem if you have the class or id of RENT and SALE parent tabs.

Comment: The "FOR SALE" & "FOR RENT" tabs are generated by Visual Composer in Wordpress. 

I'll try your solution now,

Comment: So I placed your code (which I think you missed a ; at the very end?) where you said to place it and now the sub-tab menu doesn't activate.

Comment: The tab links have a specific ID of #1430202502-2-14 & #1431978554543-1-1, so I've tried placing the following to no avail:

'#tab-1430202502-2-14,#tab-1431978554543-1-1' 
'#1430202502-2-14,#1431978554543-1-1'
'.tab-contents'

Comment: what do you mean when u say it doesn't activate?? As it doesn't show color and styles??

Comment: When I click on the sub menu tabs "all 1br 2br 3br" they don't work and show the contents

Comment: Plz do one thing. without including my code,run ur site and inspect element. Copy your significant html and paste it in comments.